# Referencing a foreign key in SQL

Tags: sql

The problem I am having is when I am trying to create a foreign key with one of the keys in the composite key of another table. SQL developer gives me the following error:

> "There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table..."

For instance I have a studentInfo, studentRoom and some arbitrary module table:

```
CREATE TABLE module 
(
    id_module VARCHAR(45),
    module_name VARCHAR(45),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_module)
);

CREATE TABLE studentInfo 
( 
    id_student INT,
    id_module VARCHAR(45),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_student, id_module),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_module) REFERENCES module(id_module) 
);

CREATE TABLE studentRoom 
( 
    id_student INT,
    id_room VARCHAR(45),
    id_module VARCHAR(45),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_student, id_room),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_module) REFERENCES module(id_module),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_student) REFERENCES studentInfo(id_student) 
);
```

This is the line of code that gives me the error:

```
FOREIGN KEY (id_student) REFERENCES studentInfo(id_student)
```

Is there a way I can circumvent this error because I need to connect both these tables with `id_student` but also need `id_student` and `id_module` to be a composite primary key in the `studentInfo` table.

**UPDATE**

After reading comments I fixed my error, but I am also wondering how I could deal with the problem if id_module was not a variable in the studentRoom table as the following did not work when creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE studentRoom (
id_student INT,
id_room VARCHAR(45),
PRIMARY KEY (id_student, id_room),
FOREIGN KEY (id_student,id_module) REFERENCES studentInfo(id_student,id_module) )
```

**UPDATE AGAIN**

So I have to add the module column to studentRoom in order for it to work.

Comment: Post your actual code, because as it is there are typos like FOREGIN instead of FOREIGN and module instead of id_module.

Comment: Your  primary key in `studentinfo` is `(id_student, id_module)` (assuming `module` is a typo). A foreign key needs to reference **all** columns of the primary key. This has been asked [many times before](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql]+"There+are+no+primary+or+candidate+keys+in+the+referenced+table")

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh i see you mean something like this: FOREIGN KEY (id_student, id_module) REFERENCES studentInfo(id_student, id_module)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after reading comments I think I should have done this for the studentRoom table:

```
CREATE TABLE studentRoom (
id_student INT,
id_room VARCHAR(45),
id_module VARCHAR(45),
PRIMARY KEY (id_student, id_room),
FOREIGN KEY (id_student,id_module) REFERENCES studentInfo(id_student,id_module) );
```

Which also resolved my error.